# Property set on a WebForms control in an event handler reverts back after event handler returns

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I'm updating properties of WebForms controls in a custom event handler, but when control returns from the event handler the property reverts back to what it was.

Here's the relevant sections of the code-behind:

```
public partial class EditorLayoutv4 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object oSender, EventArgs oEventArgs)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            moSelectedContentBlock.NeedsCommitChanged += ContentBlock_NeedsCommitChanged;
        }
        else {
            // restore fields from Page.Session[]
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Prerender(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // save fields to Page.Session[]
    }

    private void RefreshContentBlockInfoButtons()
    {
        btnSaveContentBlockChanges.Enabled = moSelectedContentBlock.NeedsCommit; // breakpoint location A
        btnDiscardContentBlockChanges.Enabled = moSelectedContentBlock.NeedsCommit;
    }

    protected void ContentBlock_NeedsCommitChanged(object oSender, EventArgs oEventArgs)
    {
        myContentBlockRow oContentBlock = (myContentBlockRow)oSender;

        if (oContentBlock.Enabled)
        {
            if (oContentBlock == moSelectedContentBlock)
            {
                RefreshContentBlockInfoButtons();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void txtContentBlockName_TextChanged(object oSender, EventArgs oEventArgs)
    {
        moSelectedContentBlock.Name = txtContentBlockName.Text;  // breakpoint location B
    }
}

public sealed class ContentBlock {
    public string Name { 
        get { return GetNameFromDB(); }
        set {
            if (value != GetNameFromDB()) {
                PutNameInDB(value);
                OnNeedsCommitChanged();
        }
    }

    private void OnNeedsCommitChanged()
    {
        RowStateChangeHandler hHandler = this.NeedsCommitChanged;

        if (hHandler != null)
        {
            hHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler NeedsCommitChanged;
}
```

Execution goes like this: when the user changes the value of a control (in this case `txtContentBlockName`), it causes the appropriate event (in this case `TextChanged`) to fire and control passes to the appropriate handler in the code-behind (in this case `txtContentBlockName_TextChanged()`).  In the `ContentBlock` object, when I set a property (in this case `Name`), the setter verifies that it's actually a change, then fires a `NeedsCommitChanged` event that's defined in the class, which this Page object subscribed to with `ContentBlock_NeedsCommitChanged` as the handler.  The handler (among other things) updates the state of the save and discard buttons according to whether the data needs to be committed to the database.  So far, so good...this all works.

Here's where the problem is:  the change of enabled state for the buttons reverts back to false at some point between when `ContentBlock_NeedsCommitChanged()` returns and control passes back to `txtContentBlockName_TextChanged()`.  I set breakpoints as shown above, then I single-step at breakpoint location B and I break at location A before I leave control of the TextChanged handler.  I put a watch on the button controls and see the Enabled property sets to true.  I keep single stepping--control passes back to `ContentBlock_NeedsCommitChanged()` and the Enabled property is still true.  Another single step takes me to `ContentBlock.OnNeedsCommitChanged()` then to the `ContentBlock.Name` setter just as I'd expect.  Of course, the button is out of scope in these two frames so I can't watch it.  On the next single step I return to `txtContentBlockName_TextChanged()` and the button is back in scope but `button.Enabled` has reverted to false.  I don't have any other code that touches the button properties.  If it matters, here's how the buttons are declared in the .aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveContentBlockChanges" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" ToolTip="Save changes you've made to this content block" OnClick="btnSaveContentBlockChanges_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnDiscardContentBlockChanges" runat="server" Text="Discard Changes" ToolTip="Discard changes you've made to this content block" OnClick="btnDiscardContentBlockChanges_Click" />
```

Appreciate any insights...thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  I'm using the `Page`'s `Session` property to store a reference to the fields I populate the first time the user brings up the page.  When I process a PostBack event, I restore those fields from `Session`.  What I missed is that the `Page` object itself is a different object than the one used to populate the fields, so anything in those fields that references something in the `Page` object references the old `Page`.  To fix this, I just move the subscribe code out of the `if (!PostBack)` block so that it occurs on every `Page_Load`.